# Adding two data frames in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

Im trying to combine two data frames in R, both with 1 column, and have them added with the columns beside each other.

Let's say I have one one data frame called names.df and another called id.df, how do I combine them (name.df and name.df) so the the names are column1 and the ids are column2?

```
names <- c('John','Peter','Sally')
names.df <- data.frame(names)


id <- c('12632','82174','27036')
id.df <- data.frame(id)
```

Comment: Best to name your dataframe something except `names`. Maybe `cbind`, `merge`?

Comment: If you have same number of rows for both the dataframes, then simple `cbind` would do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cbind`:

```
cbind(names.df, id.df)

  names    id
1  John 12632
2 Peter 82174
3 Sally 27036
```

This would generate a data frame output from the two inputs.